# Telerik RadUpload Browse button to move underneath textbox

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, telerik

I am working on a Web Forms app that requires a Telerik RadUpload control to handle file uploads. By default, the RadUpload control looks like the 
following:

[image: Current layout]

However I want the browse button to be on the next line of the file upload textbox with an additional button next to it like the following:

[image: Needed layout]

I am wondering how I can achieve this? Am I going to require some CSS to define its layout? If so how do I select this control? Or does WebForms have its own way of handling layouts altogether (I have limited experience with WebForms).

```
<telerik:RadUpload ID="tstUpload" runat="server" InitialFileInputsCount="1" MaxFileInputsCount="1" ControlObjectsVisibility="None" OverwriteExistingFiles="True"
EnableFileInputSkinning="true">
  <Localization Select="<%$ Resources:Side,Test %>" />
</telerik:RadUpload>
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### The official support for RadUpload has been discontinued in June 2013.

Don't use RadUpload, as the documentation tell you :

> #### [Caution:](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/upload/overview#upload-overview)
>
> RadUpload has been replaced by RadAsyncUpload, Telerik’s next-generation ASP.NET upload component. 
> If you are considering Telerik’s Upload control for new development, check out the  documentation of RadAsyncUpload  or the control’s product page. 
> If you are already using RadUpload in your projects, you may be interested in reading how easy the transition to RadAsyncUpload is and how you can benefit from it in this blog post. 
> The official support for RadUpload has been discontinued in June 2013 (Q2’13), although it is still be available in the suite. 
> We deeply believe that RadAsyncUpload can better serve your upload needs and we kindly ask you to transition to it to make sure you take advantage of its support and the new features we constantly add to it.

### Styling

Here is a quick step by step tutorial on [customising the rad upload](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/upload/appearance-and-styling/tutorial-on-creating-custom-skin).
Here is a quick step by step tutorial on [creating a custom RadAsyncUpload skin](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/asyncupload/appearance-and-styling/tutorial-creating-a-custom-skin).

So yes you can achieve this. Some Css can be usefull to do that or a simple Js to add a `<br/>` could be a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are the CSS to move the Select button underneath the input:

```
<style>
    .RadUpload .ruFileWrap {
        height: 46px !important;
    }
    .RadUpload_Default .ruButton {
        display: block !important;
    }
</style>
```